# I want a html code in which whenever a mouse hover image it will followed 5-6 dots(div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used following codes but not works.

HTML

```
<div class="dot"></div>
```

CSS

```
div.dot{
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#dot').css({
       left:  e.pageX,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me to code an html that contains image and on hover of that image cursor must be follow dots and when it leaves images dots wiil be removed.

Comment: You want the cursor to be replaced with dots? Or the div.dots to appear to the right of the image? I suggest looking into the css :hover selector.

Comment: change 'mousemove' to 'mouseover' ?

Comment: what "doesnt work"? Any errors? Also might help to have a fiddle.

Comment: Also be attentive you use `.dot` in css but `#dot` in js.

Comment: No idea what *"follow 5-6 dots"* even means. Take some time to read through [ask]. Then edit question with a properly detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dre67ocr/)?

Comment: "_I have used following codes and it works_". No you haven't used that code. You should mention, that it is my code from the linked fiddle ... You've totally changed your question, that is not allowed to do at SO.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have used it from that link but that not work, so i have changed my question.And specially i have written here that "I have used following code" , " Not says that i have code that".

Answer (score 0):

Simply detect the `onmouseout` and `onmouseover` events, and hide / display your dot elements accordingly.

- `onmouseout` fires when the mouse is moved off the element ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseout));
- `onmouseover` when the mouse is moved onto the element ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseover));
- The CSS `display` style changes how an element is displayed ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)), if it is set to `block` the element is displayed, if it is set to `none` the element is not displayed.

```js
var dots = $('.dot');
var pos = []
var delay = 0;

for (let n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    pos.push({x: 0, y: 0});
}

$('#img').on('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (++delay < 1) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        delay = 0;
    }
    pos[1].x = e.pageX;
    pos[1].y = e.pageY;
    pos.push(pos.shift());
    dots.each(function (idx, el) {
        el.style.left = pos[idx].x + 'px';
        el.style.top = pos[idx].y + 'px';
    });
});

$('#img').on('mouseout', function (e) {
    dots.each(function(idx, el) {
        el.style.display = "none";
    });
});

$('#img').on('mouseover', function (e) {
    dots.each(function(idx, el) {
        el.style.display = "block";
    });
});
```

```css
div.dot{
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<img id="img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0afe5fc8825e9d31844fd90101e56e06?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
```